# Javascript: Using server-sent events with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying for the first time to use `server sent events` inmy project and I'm quite excited about it. because i can finally say goodbye to AJAX. ( I love AJAX but not for what I'm doing now).

Any way, I tried to use server sent events to check for a ping from my server (php script) and if the ping happens, show a simple *alert('hello world');* in my page.

However, i don't know why I never get anything in my page.. no errors either to indicate something went wrong.

This is my Javascript server sent code:

```
var pin =localStorage.getItem("pin");

var evtSource = new EventSource("https://example.com/check-for-orders.php?pin="+pin+"");    
evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {

         var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

         alert(data);
         alert('Hello World');

}, false);
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
//header("Connection: keep-alive");

session_start();
//Don't forget to enable mod_headers module in httpd.conf.
include "../config/connect.php";
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing

$pin = $_GET['pin'];

$pin2 = $pin.', ';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE something=0 LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount2 = mysqli_num_rows($query );
if ($productCount2 > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $id2 = $row["id"];
     $full_address = $row["full_address"];
        $drop_address = $row["drop_address"];
         $uPhone = $row["uPhone"];
         $ulat = $row["ulat"];
         $ulng = $row["ulng"];
         $ORDER_ID = $row["order_id"];


 echo "event: ping\n";

echo "".$ORDER_ID." - Pick Up Location: ". $full_address ."";
echo "<br /><br />";
echo "Drop Location: ".$drop_address.", Phone: ".$uPhone."";
    }
} else {

}
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: put message in else part of your code and then try.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, sorry, i didn't get what you mean! what message?

Comment: In your above code there is else part which is currently blank, just put like this.
else { echo "There are some error"; }

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, that wouldn't do anything for my issue!

Comment: Now try to put your code in try.....catch { } block.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, can you please either leave an answer or explain what you are trying to achieve? I'm not sure what a message in else (} or catch{} would do in my case to be honest.

Comment: I post answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in try.....catch block, so if any error is occuers it show there.

```
try 
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

    session_start();
    include "../config/connect.php";

    $pin = $_GET['pin'];
    $pin2 = $pin.', ';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE something=0 LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productCount2 = mysqli_num_rows($query );
    if ($productCount2 > 0) 
    {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
       {
       $id2 = $row["id"];
       $full_address = $row["full_address"];
       $drop_address = $row["drop_address"];
       $uPhone = $row["uPhone"];
       $ulat = $row["ulat"];
       $ulng = $row["ulng"];
       $ORDER_ID = $row["order_id"];
       echo "event: ping\n";
       echo "".$ORDER_ID." - Pick Up Location: ". $full_address ."";
       echo "<br /><br />";
       echo "Drop Location: ".$drop_address.", Phone: ".$uPhone."";
     }
   } 
   else {

   }
   mysqli_close($db_conx);
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned before in the comments, using try{}, catch{}, or a message in the else{} wouldn't solve my issue I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flush your echos and stay within the specs of the output format. Put Your data in an array and use this to send

```
function sendSSEMessage( $id, $data ){
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'data:'.json_encode($data). PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

To debug your php you can call it in the cli or in a Browser directly as unfortunately unlike AJAX SSE doesn't seem to pass on strings other than the well formated ones. So you don't get to see your php output in the console.